# How to convert dates within an array to a specific format

Tags: ruby

I have an array of dates, where the dates have different formats. I would like to convert them all to the same format, however what I've tried has caused me some problems.

I get the dates from a SQL query:

```
table_birth_dates = self.class.connection("SELECT birth_date FROM #{temp_table_name}").values
```

which gives me an array of dates:

```
[
    [0] "10/3/80",
    [1] "10/3/81",
    [2] "10/3/01",
    [3] "33/33/1970",
]
```

I want to get the year as a full year like above.

I tried:

```
table_birth_dates.first.to_time
```

and got:

```
ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

I also tried:

```
Date.strptime(table_birth_dates)
```

and got:

```
no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah that is ultimately what I am working on doing, i am pretty sure it goes `month` `day` `year`.  I'm ultimately trying to flag out incorrect dates that the sftp import pulls in (hence the botched date from 1970)

Comment: Are these dates stored in the database as strings, or as some other data type?

Comment: It looks like you're storing the dates as strings without normalizing them prior to storing. Don't do that. Instead, you should convert them to dates first, then output a consistent format. I'd also recommend using a date field, not a string, for storing the values. Your database will be more efficient if you need to look up or compare Date fields than using strings.

Comment: No not yet. They are pulled from a CSV file via an SFTP import.  They ultimately are parsed and then stored.  However what I'm trying to do is test them to see if they are incorrect dates first before that process happens, because the parsing skews the actual dates.

Comment: "Parsing skews the actual dates"? Not if it's done right. It's not a trivial use of `parse` though, because it's error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others already said: Don't store arbitrary strings as date! Use your database and store dates as date or datetime. See documentation of your database. (See comment from @the-tin-man.)

That said you can try the following with your current date:

```rb
table.map! { |date|
  date_hash = Date._strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') # {:mon=>10, :mday=>3, :year=>70}

  if date_hash.nil?
    'invalid'
  else
    date_hash[:year] = date_hash[:year] + 1900 if date_hash[:year] < 1000
    Date.new(date_hash[:year], date_hash[:mon], date_hash[:mday])
  end
}
```

This gives you an array with actual dates like so:

```
[
  1980-10-03
  1981-10-03
  1901-10-03
  invalid
]
```

Of course you should do something about this `invalid` but it serves your main purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If all you dates is on the the same format as the first 3 dates you can use this con change the format of the dates:

```
dates.map! do |date|
    Date.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
end
```

If you have dates on different formats you could list the formats you have and try to parse each of them and see if you get a valid result, however dates like `33/33/1970` is not a valid date at all.

Comment: This won't work. Many dates will be parsed using `%d/%m/%y`, however, if they're US-centric they'd be parsed incorrectly. Conversely, if they're not US-centric and you try to parse them as if they were, there'd be invalid results and explosions. You have to know the origin format of the date information.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing dates isn't as straightforward as people assume when they first start working with them, because dates are represented differently around the world.

```
'10/3/80'
```

would represent "October 3, 1980" in a U.S. formatted date, but would be "March 10, 1980" in the rest of the world. And, the software has no idea which it is unless you tell it which to use. And, if your data comes from around the world you can't tell unless you know what locale the data was generated in or unless they explicitly tell you what format it's in.

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime('10/3/80', '%m/%d/%y') # => #<Date: 1980-10-03 ((2444516j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.strptime('10/3/80', '%d/%m/%y') # => #<Date: 1980-03-10 ((2444309j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Not to mention entering a plain 'date' in one Timezone can result in a different date in other Timezones, ie _1am Jan 1st_ in Australia is still _December 31_ in most of the world.

Answer (score -2):

From DB, bring date in integer format and convert back to any specific format.

Are you storing date in DB as string and trying to convert them for unique format to display?  If so, you can correct while storing the value (or) add a column in DB which gets updated whenever your date column gets inserted/updated and retrieve from new column.

Comment: Rather than describe the solution you should show example code. Like a picture, code is worth 10,000 words.